# how to design a fastapi app with independent background computation?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I've created a python main application main.py, which I invoke with `uvicorn main.main --reload`. Which of course runs the following code...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That part of the application runs constantly, reads data an processes it until the application is aborted manually. I use `asyncio` to run coroutines.

**Task**

I would like to build a small html dashboard on it, which can display the data that is constantly computed.

**Question**

How can I run these background calculations of main.py and still implement a dashboard/website with fastapi and jinja2?

- What is the best practice/architecture to structure the files: the background and fastapi app code? e.g. Is there a initial startup function in fastapi where I could invoke the background computation in a coroutine or the other way around?
- How would you invoke the application according to your recommendation?

**What I have achieved so far**

I can run the main application without any fastapi code. And I can run the dashboard without the background tasks. Both work fine independently. But fastapi does not run, when I add its code to the main application with the background computation. (How could it?!? I can only invoke either the main application or the fastapi app.)

Any architectural concepts are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approch is to use the `on_event` decorator with `startup`. The only thing to remain is to use `asyncio.create_task` to invoke the background task. As long as you don't await it, it will not block and thus fastapi/uvicorn can continue to serve any http request.

```
my_service = MyService()

@app.on_event('startup')
async def service_tasks_startup():
    """Start all the non-blocking service tasks, which run in the background."""
    asyncio.create_task(my_service.start_processing_data())
```

Also, with this said, any request can consume the data of this background service.

```
@app.get("/")
def root():
    return my_service.value
```

Think of `MyService` as any class of your liking. Kafka consumption, computations, etc. Of course, the `value` is just an example attribute of the Class MyService.

Comment: Is only non-blocking if `start_processing_data()` is also defined as `async`.

Comment: asyncio uses weak reference tracking for tasks, so your created task may be GC:ed

Comment: @Henrik valid point. What do you recommend?

Comment: make `my_service` hold the task reference, run `start` on IT instead

Answer (score 2):

Fastapi doesn't run because it cant be reached by python interpreter untill it complete your computations. You should start your web app independently of the main process, I strongly recommend you to use `docker-compose`.
As fastapi recommends you, you should use `Dramatiq` or `Celery` for huge background tasks, or you can just run separate service in compose services, for example:

```
# background.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# main.py
app = FastAPI()
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
  web-app-interface:
    command: uvicorn main.main ...
  my-daemon:
    command: python background.py
```

You can make them communicate with a message broker, such as RabbitMQ etc.
And never use multiprocessing with uvicorn, it can cause process leak, bcz uvicorn rules it's own workers.

Comment: thanks and yes, that is how I would do it as well. But... I consume data from a kafka topics (in the background process) and then I would want to append the new events to a dataframe (it doesn't matter if the dataframe is lost upon restart). The fastapi REST calls should then return fractions of that dataframe. Thus, I cannot separate the applications. Do you understand the constraint?

Comment: You can write result of background task to database and read it in your api endpoints.

Comment: I feel saving it to a database makes little sense since I consume messages, thus they are ALREADY persisted. Repersisting is of no value. The dashboard depends on these messages ( I want to push them with websockets to the dashboard). Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: If you don't really need to save them, you can use any MQ, as I mentioned before.

Comment: Yegor, it makes very little sense to copy an incoming message of a kafka topic again to another MQ. I see no value in duplicating an action (since I know the kafka infrastructure is under my control). But be certain, you have my gratitude for sharing your ideas. Appreciated.